Need help with riggify
I’m new to blender and I’m having trouble with riggify. Every time I click deform with automatic weights it causes my character to expand. Can someone tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Where did your model come from and did you apply the rotation and scale (Ctrl-A > Rotation & Scale) to it and the Scale to the armature before doing the parenting?
